# FFmpeg stucks for few seconds on start

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut and resize video on Android(but it is similar on MacOS) , but when I run the ffmpeg command it returns me

> frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=

It repeats for about 20 sec (I have 4K video with 3 sec duration).

Is there any way to improve process speed? Here is example of my ffmpeg command

> ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01.82 -to 00:02.94 -vf scale=500:1024 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 500k -b:a 96k output.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `-ss` after the input performs a decoded frame seek, which is slower. Switch to demuxer seek

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:01.82 -to 00:02.94 -i input.mp4 -vf scale=500:1024 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 500k -b:a 96k output.mp4
```

`-to` for demuxer was only recently added, so get a current git version. Else, use `-t` with the calculated duration.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of this options did not work for me, using -t instead of -to made it even slower and setting -ss and -to before input is not available, it just fails

Comment: ok, thank you, this report helped me to understand what is going on. The problem was that "-to" param belongs to output file in some way, but "ss" param can belong either to input file. I'll edit your answer to let people see correct answer

Comment: No, my answer is correct. *-to for demuxer was only recently added*. For older versions, you have to use `-t` (as an input argument)

Comment: ok, right, -t works for me too on Android, just do not have possibility to build newer version for that